# Can I access a WSL sshfs mounted location from windows explorer?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel, sshfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following...

```
xx@BigBoy:~ $sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/my.pem ec2-user@ec2-3-144-108-204.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/my-drive/data efs
xx@BigBoy:~ $ls -al efs/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx  1 xx xx 6144 Jan 15 21:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 45 xx xx 4096 Jan 15 21:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 xx xx    0 Jan 15 21:44 test.txt
```

But when I try to go to the same folder in Windows explorer I get

[image]

Is there a way to get this to work?